# Efficient way to compute rolling zscore in C++

Tags: c++

i am trying speed up my implementation of rolling zscore.
What I'm doing: I've a matrix features (nxm). And each column of features I wanna apply a  rolling window that are different from one column to the other.
So right now, i 'm doing:

- for each row >= maximum rollong window
- for each column of feature

  - get the vector from i - rolling window to i

    - compute mean, std, zscore

What i've done:

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>

using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;

double computeMean(const VectorXf &v) 
{ 
   double sum = 0;  
   for ( auto e : v) { sum += e; } 
   return sum / v.rows(); 
}

double computeStdDeviation(const VectorXf &v, double mean) 
{ 
   double varianceSum = 0; 
   for ( auto x : v) { varianceSum += ( x - mean) * ( x - mean); } 
   double variance = varianceSum / v.rows(); 
   return sqrt(variance); 
}

double zScore(double x, double stdDev, double mean)
{  
    if (stdDev > 0) return (x - mean) / stdDev; 
    return -5;
} 

MatrixXf NormalizeData(const MatrixXf& features, const vector<int> shifts) {
    int max = *max_element(shifts.begin(), shifts.end());
    MatrixXf df(features.rows() - max, features.cols());

    for (size_t i = max; i < features.rows(); ++i) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < features.cols(); ++j) {
            VectorXf vec = features(seq(i-shifts[j]+1,i), j); // get a vector of size shifts[j]       
            double elem = vec(last);
            double mean = computeMean(vec);
            double std = computeStdDeviation(vec, mean);
            df(i-max, j) = zScore(elem , std, mean);
        }
    }
    return df;
}
```

shifts being a vector [10, 20, 30, ...]

But even with as low as 500k rows, this takes a very long time.
Any one has an idea on how to speed this up please?

Update:

I tried

```
    std::for_each(std::execution::par, features.rowwise().begin()+max-1, features.rowwise().end(), [] (auto&& row) {
        int index = row.index - max + 1;
        if (index % 100000 == 0) std::cout << "NormalizeData Filename: " << filename << " - " << index << " / " << df.rows() << endl;
        df(index, 0) = row(0);

        for (size_t j = 0; j < shifts.size(); ++j) {
...}}
```

But it says "max" is not captured,
"df" is not captured
"shifts" is not captured...

Comment: as each row is independent, you may want to use multithreading for this with openmp, this is embarrassingly parallel problem, you could also get the compiler to emit AVX instructions for some of these operations.

Comment: You could also use one of the standard paralell execution policies.

Comment: I'm still new in C++ and unfamliliar with this. Looking at it, you suggest then std::execution::parallel_policy for the j loop ?

Comment: I'd place it on the outer loop for best effect. That way it won't have to distribute work to the worker threads so many times.

Comment: I don't manage to make this work though : std::for_each(std::execution::par, std::begin(features(seq(max, last), all)), std::end(features), [&](int i){

Comment: I don't know much about Eigen, but something like this might work: `std::for_each(std::execution::par, features.rowwise().begin(); features.rowwise().end(); [] (auto&& row) { ... });`

Comment: I have no instance of overloaded function "std::for_each" matches the argument list

Comment: Sorry, I got `;` instead of `,` in two places I noticed. `std::for_each(std::execution::par, features.rowwise().begin(), features.rowwise().end(), [] (auto&& row) { ... });` Also note that you need to compile with C++17 or later.

Comment: i get many errors: error: ‘features’ is not captured - note: ‘const MatrixXf& features’ declared here error: ‘df’ is not captured df(i-max, 0) = features(i, 0); error: ‘i’ was not declared in this scope df(i-max, 0) = features(i, 0); note: ‘Eigen::MatrixXf df’ declared here

Comment: `features` doesn't need to be captured. You get each row in `row`.

Comment: I've updated the code. But it does not let me compile cause of the several element "not captured"

Comment: If you have something not captured in lambda, make sure to pass it in `[]` block, e.g. `[&features]` - this is an example, I'm not saying it's the right capture you need to make. Also, you might try to capture everything by reference by using `[&]`, but it's a bit less safer solution.

Comment: Indeed! Thanks. But I used an i in the outer for loop to then get the matrix from i-max to i. Here I have a row, how can i do the VectorXf vec = features(seq(i-shifts[j]+1,i), j); line now ?

Comment: you know with openmp you could've just added `#pragma parallel for` and went on with your day , the only downside is that openmp's threadpool sometimes causes issues on very old systems with limited TLB sizes, so its addition to large projects should be investigated first.